# Hypothesis testing on two disproportionate samples

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, effect-size

I want to conduct hypothesis testing on conversion rate of two disproportionate samples. One contains 20k Data points and other contains 180k datapoints. 
How can I do a hypothesis testing on such dataset as I know size has an effect on p value and result would be more biased towards higher size.
Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean when you say "result would be more biased towards higher size"?

Comment: This question already has answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175321/241093) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/283266/241093).